# Store viewstate of group of checkboxes

Tags: asp.net, checkbox

I have a problem with checkboxes in ASP.NET. I want to store their values after users submit the form and some fields are invalid. For example, in register page, after user submitted the register form, users don't want to re-check some checkboxes again. I highly appreciate any helps.

Thank you so much :-)

Comment: The default behavior is to store a checkbox's state after a postback. If you want to store it after a page refresh, you'll probably want to store it in a cookie, database, or somewhere like that.

Comment: Thank you, because I used plain html code, now I change to CheckBoxesList

Answer (score 0):

Once completed the Sumbit, Once again you retrieve the Checked CheckBox value from the DataBase(what you have stored) and Check the CheckBox as per the value you stored.
Based on the DataBase records, you give like this:

```
    CheckBox1.Checked = true;
```